# How to change Reset password email template in Laravel Fortify?

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I'm using fortify for authentication stuff, however I need to change the text in the "Reset Password" email template automatically sent by fortify. I  can't find a way to achieve this.

Also is it possible to make the template editable from Nova ? I have a MailTemplate Resource in Nova to allow changing email template from Nova, but I can't achieve this for the "Reset Password email" since it's sent by fortify and can't find a way to control it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortify uses the core notification system from Laravel to send the password reset email. The specific file responsible for this is the `PasswordReset.php` file located at `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications`.

The simplest way to customise the email that is sent would be to make a copy of the `PasswordReset` file and save it to your project somewhere (e.g. `App\Notifications`) with a different name (optional).

Once copied and you've customised it to your liking, you'll then need to overwrite the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your `User` model which is inherited from the `CanResetPassword` trait on the `Authenticatable` class.

```php
/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new App\Notifications\CustomResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

There are some other notifications you might want to overwrite whilst you're there such as the `VerifyEmail` notification.

Regarding managing the content/layout in Nova, I suspect that is possible. You might need to write a custom package to read `mardown` files is that's what you use in the email, either that or define some placeholders for text which can be stored in the database and managed via Nova.